# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');  
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const config = require('./config.json');
const prefix = config.prefix;
const glois = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("global.json", "utf8"));

const escapeRegex = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready`);
    const activities_list = [({ activity: { name: `${client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, b) => a + b.memberCount, 0).toLocaleString()} Usern auf ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servern zu` }, status: 'online' }), ({ activity: { name: `${prefix} | Kanax in Discord ` }, status: 'online' })]

      setInterval(() => {
          const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
          client.user.setPresence(activities_list[index]);
      }, 15000); // Runs this every 15 seconds.
  })

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const sender = message.author; 
 const channelmtn = message.mentions.channels.first()

 const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(prefix)})\\s*`);
    if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

    const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);
 const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim(/ +/g);
 const cmd = args.toLowerCase().split();

 if(cmd == "ping") {
   let Pong = "Pong!"
   var ping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
   let pembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle(client.user.username + "'s Ping")
   .setDescription(`:hourglass: **Latency**\n${ping}ms\n:heartbeat: **API**\n${client.ws.ping}ms`)
   .setColor("#00ffff")
   await message.channel.send('Pingen...').catch(console.error)
   .then(async message => {
    setTimeout(() => { message.edit(Pong); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => { message.edit(pembed); }, 2000);
  })
 };

 if (cmd == "invite") {
   let invembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle("Du kannst mich hier einladen")
   .setURL("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=711620266492690474&permissions=537390145&scope=bot")
   .setColor("#00ffff")
   message.channel.send(invembed)
  };

  if(cmd == "stop")
if (message.author.id === "602935358316871709") {
  console.log(`${sender.username} (${sender.id}) hat den Bot gestoppt`)
  message.channel.send(`<@${sender.id}> hat den Bot gestoppt`)
  process.exit();
}

if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "set global")) {
if(!channelmtn) return message.reply("Erwähne einen Textchannel!")

    glois[message.guild.id] = {
      globalchat: channelmtn.id
    };
    fs.writeFile("global.json", JSON.stringify(glois), err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    let setembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Setup")
    .setDescription(`Der Globalchat wurde zu <#${channelmtn.id}> gesetzt`)
    message.channel.send(setembed);
    };

  const sett = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("global.json", "utf8"));
  if (!sett[message.guild.id]) {
    sett[message.guild.id] = {
      globalchat: "698616682452746281"
    };
  }

  const globis = sett[message.guild.id].globalchat;
  if(message.channel.id === globis) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(message.author.tag)
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL) 
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setFooter(`Coming soon`)
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
      try{
        client.channels.cache.get(glois[message.guild.id].globalchat).send(embed)
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
      } 
    });
};
});

client.login(config.Token)
```

If I send `gk!set global #test` then in the console will stay this

```js
(node:8216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
warning.js:32
(node:8216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What's the content of `global.json` and `config.json`? Needs to be an array or object, can't be empty. Also could be that you have false object notation, which an ide/linter should tell you,=

Answer (score 0):

It simply means your JSON isn't valid JSON.